# QCombobox finData method always returns -1 with numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pyside2, qcombobox

I have a problem trying to get the index of some data on the combobox when a numpy array is used to add the items, while if I use a list the result is the expected.

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
import numpy as np


app = QtWidgets.QApplication()

heights_list = [0.52, 1, 2, 3, 4, 12.57, 14.97] 
heights_array = np.array([0.52, 1, 2, 3, 4, 12.57, 14.97])

combo_list = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
for height in heights_list:
    combo_list.addItem(f"{height:.2f} m", height)

combo_array = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
for height in heights_array:
    combo_array.addItem(f"{height:.2f} m", height)

print(combo_list.findData(14.97))  # Print 6
print(combo_array.findData(14.97)) # Print -1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`findData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#findData) method uses the model's [`match()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#match) method, and the match method uses the [`QVariant`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html)s for comparison. For its part PySide2(also PyQt5) to have compatibility does [`PyObject`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html#c.PyObject) conversions (which is the representation of a python object in C/C++) to basic types such as int, float, etc. but it does not know how to convert a numpy object and then it only stores the pointer, and when comparing [`QVariant`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html) that stores pointers it compares the memory address, but being 2 different objects it will always return that they are not the same object.

Comment: In the end I ended up using the numpy array `tolist` method, and filling the combobox from a list.